# Point of type Foo func() foo

Tags: go

I'm new to Go, and I was going over a couple of written pieces of code, and noticed a lot of them had functions initialized as

```
type Foo func() foo
```

where `Foo` is the type name, and `foo` is the return type. I was wondering what the point of this is?

Comment: Because methods can then be added to `Foo`, allowing `Foo` to satisfy an interface.

Answer (score 7):

In Go, functions are first-class types; they can be parameters to other functions, returned from functions, or used as `struct` fields, `map` values, slice elements, and so on. Defining a named function type makes it easier to do this, as you'd likely see in any code where you've seen this pattern. You can also define methods on these types (yes, a function type can have methods defined on it!), such as is done with `net/http`'s `HandlerFunc`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually trying to use this to connect to a DB so that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Another benefit is the ability to semantically enrich an otherwise generic (probably complex) `func`. Or did you already refer to this via "makes it easier to do this"?